# Display table tag in struts 2

Tags: struts2

```
<display:table export="true"  id="data" name="${sessionScope.forbesList}"requestURI="">


                <a href="#" rel="tooltip" content="<span>

                        Name:<s:property value="#data.rank" /><br/>
                        Email: <a><s:property value="#data.name" /></a><br/>
                        Phone:<s:property value="#data.age" /> </span>">   <display:column property="rank" title="Rank" sortable="true"   /></a>
        <display:column property="name" title="Name" sortable="true"  />
        <display:column property="age" title="Age" sortable="true"  />

    </display:table>
```

In Struts 2 I'm trying  to use `<s:property>` tag inside `<display :column>` tag but I can only see the `<display:column>` values and not the values that I access with `<s:property>`. How to do it?

Comment: I'm sorry I have read your message a few times and I can't understand what your issue is.  Is your issue setting the content attribute in the <a> tag?

Comment: Actually I want to show the name,rank and age as a tooltip.So I tried to display it using <s:property> but its not showing

Answer (score 0):

#1: Anchor (`<A>`) Tag does not have any `content` attribute.

Please refer to [the documentation](http://www.htmlquick.com/reference/tags/a.html) to see which attributes it supports and how to use them.

---

#2: in HTML, when putting the character `"` into an attribute of a Tag, you can:

- substitute `"` with `'`, like in

  - `myAttribute="this is 'right'"` or
  - `myAttribute='this is "right" too'`, or
- encode the `"` with the html entity `&quot;`, like in

  - `myAttribute="this is &quot;right&quot;"`

You must encode the `<` and `>` too, with `&lt;` (Less Than) or `&gt;` (Greater Than).

---

#3: that said, you could put your HTML inside the Anchor Tag, in the place where it is supposed to be inserted, like :

```
<a href="#" rel="tooltip"> 
      Name:<s:property value="#data.rank" />
</a>
```

but, in your case, you are injecting a lot of HTML, including *another* Anchor, that is not possible. I think you should simply use a div or something similar as a container, like:

```
<div rel="tooltip" >
   <span>
      Name:<s:property value="#data.rank" /><br/>
      Email: <a><s:property value="#data.name" /></a><br/>
      Phone:<s:property value="#data.age" /> 
   </span>
</div>
```

Resolve this before worrying about DisplayTag

---

**EDIT**

#4 
Change

```
<s:property value="#data.rank" />
```

(and all the other tags) to

```
<s:property value="#attr.data.rank" />
```

`#attr` is the OGNL used to access the `pageContext`,

if it is available, otherwise it searches request, session and application scopes.

Comment: actually the problem is that <s:property> is not retrieving the value.I am trying to use #data.propertyName where data is the id in the dispaly table.What is the way to do it?

Comment: Actually the problems are all the listed above, plus the wrong syntax in `<s:property />` and the fact that a tooltip *should* not lie inside a table. I'll edit with the correct `<s:property/>` syntax, but i strongly suggest you to understand the previous problems before.

Comment: Actually `#attr` searches PageContext if it is available, otherwise it searches request, session and application scopes.

Comment: Actually I've lost a lot of time here with no upvotes nor accepted answer... lol :)